# Vectorize weighted sum matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, weighted-average

I was trying to vectorize a certain weighted sum but couldn't figure out how to do it. I have created a simple minimal working example below. I guess the solution involves either bsxfun or reshape and kronecker products but I still have not managed to get it working.

```
rng(1);
N = 200;
T1 = 5;
T2 = 7;

A = rand(N,T1,T2);
w1 = rand(T1,1);
w2 = rand(T2,1);

B = zeros(N,1);

for i = 1:N
for j1=1:T1
for j2=1:T2
    B(i) = B(i) + w1(j1) * w2(j2) * A(i,j1,j2);
end
end
end

A = B;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `bsxfun`, `reshape` and `permute` to accomplish this.

We first use `permute` to move the `N` dimension to the 3rd dimension of `A`. We then multiply `w1` and the transpose of `w2` to create a grid of weights. We can then use `bsxfun` to perform element-wise multiplication (`@times`) between this grid and each "slice" of `A`. We can then reshape the 3D result into M x N and sum across the first dimension.

```
B = sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times, w1 * w2.', permute(A, [2 3 1])), [], N)).';
```

**Update**

There's actually a simpler approach which would use matrix multiplication to perform the summation for you. It unfortunately has to be broken into

```
% Create the grid of weights
W = w1 * w2.';

% Perform matrix multiplication between a 2D version of A and the weights
B = reshape(A, N, []) * W(:);
```

Or you could use `kron` to create the flattened grid of weights:

```
B = reshape(A, N, []) * kron(w2, w1);
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. This works perfectly. I did try use bsxfun and reshape  but didn't figure it out. Thank you very much! I can only accept the answer in 6 minutes :)

Comment: I have edited slightly the question. Is the answer easily generalizable for a three dimensional sum?

Comment: @volcompt It looks like this solution worked well for your 2D weighting question but really the 3D question is a different beast. It is best to accept this (if it works for you) and [ask a different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43485/318672) with your new question.