# Triple weighted sum

Tags: matlab, vectorization, weighted-average

I was trying to vectorize a certain weighted sum but couldn't figure out how to do it. I have created a simple minimal working example below. I guess the solution involves either bsxfun or reshape and kronecker products but I still have not managed to get it working.

```
rng(1);
N = 200;
T1 = 5;
T2 = 7;
T3 = 10;


A = rand(N,T1,T2,T3);
w1 = rand(T1,1);
w2 = rand(T2,1);
w3 = rand(T3,1);

B = zeros(N,1);

for i = 1:N
 for j1=1:T1
  for j2=1:T2
   for j3=1:T3
    B(i) = B(i) + w1(j1) * w2(j2) * w3(j3) * A(i,j1,j2,j3);
   end
  end
 end
end

A = B;
```

For the two dimensional case there is a smart answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108702/vectorize-weighted-sum-matlab/39108811#39108811).

Comment: do you need to generalise? because if so I'd rephrase your N, T1, T2, T3 as an array.

Comment: I actually just wanted the three dimensional case. But the generalization might be useful for someone else :)

Comment: generalisation below :)

Comment: Thought you might be interested in benchmarks. For 1000 iterations performed in Octave, the looped version took 20 minutes, my version took 1.66s with repmat and 0.92s without, and Suever's took 0.77s. :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou great! Very useful!

Comment: PS. and 0.40s in Julia (with my method adapted to Julia :p )

Comment: Yes, at some point I should learn julia. I program in Matlab and Fortran,learning Julia should not have a huge fixed cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an additional multiplication to modify the `w1 * w2'` grid from the previous answer to then multiply by `w3` as well. You can then use matrix multiplication again to multiply with a "flattened" version of `A`.

```
W = reshape(w1 * w2.', [], 1) * w3.';
B = reshape(A, size(A, 1), []) * W(:);
```

You could wrap the creation of weights into it's own function and make this generalizable to `N` weights. Since this uses recursion, `N` is limited to your current recursion limit (500 by default).

```
function W = createWeights(W, varargin)
    if numel(varargin) > 0
        W = createWeights(W(:) * varargin{1}(:).', varargin{2:end});
    end
end
```

And use it with:

```
W = createWeights(w1, w2, w3);
B = reshape(A, size(A, 1), []) * W(:);
```

**Update**

Using part of @CKT's very good suggestion to use `kron`, we could modify `createWeights` just a little bit.

```
function W = createWeights(W, varargin)
    if numel(varargin) > 0
        W = createWeights(kron(varargin{1}, W), varargin{2:end});
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic behind it:

```
ww1 = repmat (permute (w1, [4, 1, 2, 3]), [N, 1,  T2, T3]);
ww2 = repmat (permute (w2, [3, 4, 1, 2]), [N, T1, 1,  T3]);
ww3 = repmat (permute (w3, [2, 3, 4, 1]), [N, T1, T2, 1 ]);

B = ww1 .* ww2 .* ww3 .* A;
B = sum (B(:,:), 2)
```

You can avoid `permute` by creating `w1`, `w2`, and `w3` in the appropriate dimension in the first place. Also you can use `bsxfun` instead of `repmat` as appropriate for extra performance, I'm just showing the logic here and `repmat` is easier to follow.

**EDIT:** Generalised version for arbitrary input dimensions:

```
Dims   = {N, T1, T2, T3};  % add T4, T5, T6, etc as appropriate
Params = cell (1, length (Dims));

Params{1} = rand (Dims{:});
for n = 2 : length (Dims)
  DimSubscripts = ones (1, length (Dims));  DimSubscripts(n) = Dims{n};
  RepSubscripts = [Dims{:}];  RepSubscripts(n) = 1;
  Params{n} = repmat (rand (DimSubscripts), RepSubscripts);
end

B = times (Params{:});
B = sum (B(:,:), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Again, you couldn't generalize this that well for N-D unless you made some function to construct the Kronecker product vector, but how about

```
  A = reshape(A, N, []) * kron(w3, kron(w2, w1));
```

Answer (score 1):

If we're going the route of having functions anyway, and are favoring performance over elegance/brevity, then consider this:

```
function B = weightReduce(A, varargin)

    B = A;
    for i = length(varargin):-1:1
        N = length(varargin{i});
        B = reshape(B, [], N) * varargin{i};
    end

end
```

This is the performance comparison I see:

```
tic;
for i = 1:10000
    W = createWeights(w1,w2,w3);
    B = reshape(A, size(A,1), [])*W(:);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.920821 seconds.
tic; 
for i = 1:10000
    B2 = weightReduce(A, w1, w2, w3); 
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.484470 seconds.
```